# How to use Througput & Synchronizing Timer together in a single JMeter Test Plan

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a JMeter Test Plan where I am using different Timers like **Throughput Timer, Constant Timer & Synchronizing Timer.**

Throughput timer is in root of test plan, Where as other timers are only applicable within scope of controllers.

```
TestPlan
- ThroughPut Timer

-- ThreadGroup

---- Controller-Login
---------- Constant Synchronizing Timer

---- Controller-Action1
---------- Constant Timer (for Think Time delay)

---- Controller-Action2
---------- Constant Timer (for Think Time delay)
```

- Throughput Timer has Target throughput at 180 and it is applied to all active threads. Which means 3 reqs/sec.
- Constant Timer is used to give delay between samplers and it has varying delays.

Now, when I run Test plan with only 'Throughput Timer' enabled, then it works fine. I get expected results (approximately 3 reqs/sec) for all requests ( except first one - reasons unknown!) [check graph screenshot](http://snag.gy/kOrG9.jpg).

However, when I enable 'Constant Timers' as well, then JMeter fails to control the throughput. Almost all of requests cross 20 reqs/sec mark. [check Transactions/sec graph screenshot.](http://snag.gy/Gr7jw.jpg)

Apparently, it seems that there is conflict when I use 2 or more than 2 type of timers in JMeter. Has any one a solution or workaround for this scenario as I want to implement think-time along with controlling through put.